# Azure DevOps Variable secrets between tasks jobs issecret=true

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, secret-key

My Keyvault secrets are appearing in clear text in the console, I tried to set the variable to a secret:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nsg-list;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(nsg-list)"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nsg-rules;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(nsg-rules)"
```

Now the build are failing, if I remove the `issecret=true` the builds work again.

I need to pass the variables between tasks and jobs, is there a better way of doing this ?

```
pool:
     vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
   steps:
     - task: AzureKeyVault@1
       displayName: Read variables from keyvault
       inputs:
         azureSubscription: Sandbox
         keyVaultName: "sandbox"
         secretsFilter: '*'
     - script: |
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backend_storage_account_name;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(backend-storage-account-name)"
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backend_storage_container_name;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(backend-storage-container-name)"
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backend_access_key;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(backend-access-key)"
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tenant-id;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(tenant-id)"
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=app-id;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(app-id)"
```

Comment: What is the error when the build failing?

Comment: My Keyvault secrets are appearing in clear text in the console - is the error not very secure

Answer (score 3):

you need to explicitly set them as environment variables with something like this:

```
env:
  var1: $(your_var_name)
```

in each step you intend to use them. and then you. can use them as environment variables

Comment: that resolves the passing between jobs / tasks but what about builds fail if you add issecret=true;isOutput=true \n          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=backend_storage_account_name;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(backend-storage-account-name)"
but builds are successful is you remove issecret=true

Comment: that works for me just fine, not sure what do you mean

Comment: I think the OP is saying that when you use isSecret=true for task.setvariable nothing is being returned to the variable. This is the exact issue we are facing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is understanding what these variables truly are. From the OP

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=nsg-list;issecret=true;isOutput=true]$(nsg-list)"
```

In this context these are Task Variables, it would be akin to creating the variable in the Variables section of the pipeline. What we have noticed in our testing is that isOutput will prepend the task name onto the variable, which was not terribly convenient for us, so we opted to not use isOutput.

In order to make the secrets available on linux we just exported those variables and were able to move forward with our pipeline.